# What URL while adding New Service Hooks Subscription in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks, azure-service-hooks

I tried to create a New Service Hooks Subscription in Azure Devops, where notification will be send to Google Chat when build status will be failed. But in the 'Action' section I must provide some URL which is required and I have no idea what URL it should be.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be the system-generated incoming webhook URL in Google Chat - https://developers.google.com/chat/how-tos/webhooks#setting_up_an_incoming_webhook

When the build failed, azure devops service hook will make an http request to this URL to trigger the operation in Google Chat side.